# How to setup CouchDB for Front End / Integration Testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, couchdb, teamcity, integration-testing

I am researching CouchDB at the moment to use in the coming project. It has features I like to use however being new to NoSQL I would like to understand how to setup CouchDB when doing front end / integration testing. I am doing BDD so basically between each scenario I need to be able to rollback / reset / restore CouchDB so that scenarios don't have data dependencies with each other. But I yet to find a clean way to do it. So any suggestions would be welcomed.

Would it be just as simple as deleting db from CouchDB after each scenario is complete?

Answer (score 1):

That should work. You can look at the testing approach in couchdb-python for an example:

http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/source/browse/couchdb/tests/testutil.py